# Other way to get/set Visual Basic ObservableCollection property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, observablecollection

Id like to know if there are other way to set/get value of an observableCollection Property. Please see below example

Let say i have

```
Public Class Record
     public Property Field1 as string
     public Property Field2 as string
End Class
```

---

```
Public RecordCollection as new ObservableCollection(Of Record)
Public sRecord as Record

Public Sub TestRecord()
    sRecord = new Record
    sRecord.Field1 = "test"
    sRecord.Field2 = "test2"
    RecordCollection.add(sRecord)

    listview1.ItemsSource = RecordCollection

End Sub
```

My Question is How can i set or gets Record properties like below example?

```
Public Sub TestRecord()
    sRecord = new Record
    sRecord("Field1") = "test"
    sRecord("Field2") = "test2"
End Sub
```

or is there any other way to this?

Comment: Please tell us purpose of that approach. You can use `System.Reflection` for accessing properties by names.

Comment: you could use a dictionary to store the values of field1, field2 etc 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

Comment: Hi @5uperdan, Do you mean change Record Class to this?  
Public Class Record  
     public Property Field1 as  New Dictionary(Of String, String)  
     public Property Field2 as  New Dictionary(Of String, String)  
End Class

Comment: @Fabio, 
Hi Sir, the purpose is to automatically assigned values to property by getting the name from database field. Doing my question return this error "cannot be indexed because it has no default property"

Comment: Use [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) - that exactly what you trying to accomplish

Comment: @bob see Alex B's answer. That's what i was proposing

Comment: @5uperdan that was actually i was looking yesterday. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here example of using `System.Reflection` for your case

Testing class

```
Public Class Record
   Public Property Field1 As String
   Public Property Field2 As String
End Class
```

Example

```
Dim data As New DataTable()
data.Columns.Add("Field1", GetType(String))
data.Columns.Add("Field2", GetType(String))

Dim dr As DataRow
dr = data.NewRow()
dr.SetField("Field1", "0")
dr.SetField("Field2", "Zero")
data.Rows.Add(dr)

dr = data.NewRow()
dr.SetField("Field1", "1")
dr.SetField("Field2", "One")
data.Rows.Add(dr)

For Each row As DataRow In data.Rows
    Dim temp As New Record()
    For Each prop As PropertyInfo In GetType(Record).GetProperties()
        If data.Columns.Contains(prop.Name) = True Then
           prop.SetValue(temp, row(prop.Name))
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine($"{temp.Field1}, {temp.Field2}")
Next
```

Will print result in the console:

```
0, Zero
1, One
```

But again, consider of using [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or some other ORM(object-relational mapper) framework.

Comment: Thank you very much i am now reviewing EF6

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Default Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6z814t.aspx) functionality in the Record class:

```
Public Class Record
        Private fields As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Public Property Field1 As String
            Get
                Return fields("Field1")
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                fields("Field1") = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Public Property Field2 As String
        'Same code as Field1 but with "Field2" of course

        Default Public Property Item(field As String)
            Get
                Return fields(field)
            End Get
            Set(value)
                fields(field) = value
            End Set
        End Property
End Class
```

Access is then possible like:

```
   Dim record As New Record
   record("Field1") = "Hello Default Property!"
   record.Field2 = "Hello Field2 !"
   Console.WriteLine(record("Field1"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex B